# Counter ISP speed throttling

Tags: isp

So my ISP, like many others, likes to throttle my internet speed. YouTube streaming works fine. Any other streaming service works crap. But what hurts the most is torrent speed throttling. Now I know there are VPNs to get around this but I had another theoretical solution in mind:

My data plan allows me a max download speed of around 600 KBps (average). But torrents are restricted to 200KBps max. Is there any way I can split the torrent download into two parts and download them on different devices? And if so, then will using this method allow me a combined speed of 400KBps?

I know it's a stupid question but I really want to get around this throttling.

Comment: There are VPNs and other ways to hide the kind of traffic you're using, but those are out of scope for SuperUser.com .

Answer (score 1):

No.

Basically all generic consumer IPv4 A.N. Other ISP routers function as NAT gateways. Your ISP only ever sees one device, the router, and can't tell what's behind it. Therefore they throttle based on total traffic of a given type, not per connection or device.

Furthermore, BitTorrent already splits downloads into multiple connections to/from different peers, so it already looks like "multiple devices doing multiple downloads" as it is, if your ISP were looking for such a thing.